# Scheduler in syncfusion for angular

Tags: angular, timetable

I'm getting the below error while using the command

```
ng add @syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule
```

Can someone help me with this error (I'm using Angular 8)

Or else can someone suggest time-table from different site

Thanks in Advance.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-select-dropdown/dist/assets/style.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/ngx-select-dropdown/dist/assets/style.css)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   **Error: Failed to find** '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-material-theme/styles/material.css'
>     in [
>       C:\Users\yasikraamp\Desktop\timetable\hostel_proto\node_modules\ngx-select-dropdown\dist\assets
>     ]
>       at C:\Users\yasikraamp\Desktop\timetable\hostel_proto\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13
>       at async Promise.all (index 0)

Answer (score -1):

Add `@syncfusion/ej2-material-theme` to your package.json